# how to post images from client side to Next.js API endpoint and then to Django REST Framework API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, next.js

I attempted to create a feature that allows users to upload product images to an ecommerce website. My plan initially was to receive the form submission from the client side in Next.js, and then pass it to the built-in Next.js API endpoint. I wanted to add an authorization token to the header and post it to the Django REST framework API, where I save the image and connect it to the user model using a foreign key.

Although posting the image directly from the client side to the Django server worked well, I needed to add an authorization token to the header to retrieve the user in the backend. As I used the HTTP-only method, so I had to post it to the Next.js API endpoint.

The problem is I keep running in to is when I post it to the api end point I couldn’t get the image directly to repost it to a djano api end point. Any help would be appreciated.

Nextjs client side code.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Oval } from 'react-loader-spinner';

function ProductUpload() {
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.auth.loading)

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        alt: '',
    })
    
    const {
        name,
        alt,
    } = formData;
    
    
    const onChange = e => setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    
    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()

  
        const file = e.target.file.files[0];

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', name);
        formData.append('product_image.alt', alt);
        formData.append('product_image.img', file);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('api/upload', formData, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
            });
            console.log(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
    }

  return (
    <div>
     <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold my-2'>Register Page</h1>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <h3 className='text-lg text-blue-700 font-medium'>Create an account</h3>
            <div className='h-[1px] bg-black w-[25%]'> 
            </div>
            <div className='space-y-1 '>
                <label
                className='block'
                htmlFor='name'>name</label>
                <input 
                className='bg-blue-100 w-[25%] py-1 px-2'
                type="text"
                onChange={onChange} 
                name="name" 
                placeholder='name'
                value={name}/>
            </div>
            
            <div className='h-[0.5px] bg-black w-[25%]'> 
            </div>
            <div className='space-y-1 '>
                <label
                className='block'
                htmlFor='alt'>alt</label>
                <input 
                className='bg-blue-100 w-[25%] py-1 px-2'
                type="text"
                onChange={onChange} 
                name="alt" 
                placeholder='alt'
                value={alt}/>
            </div>
            
            <div className='h-[0.5px] bg-black w-[25%]'> 
            </div>
            <div className='space-y-1 '>
                <label
                className='block'
                htmlFor='alt'>IMG</label>
                <input 
                className='bg-blue-100 w-[25%] py-1 px-2'
                type="file" name="file" multiple 
                />    
            </div>

        <button className=' bg-gray-300 py-2 px-6' type="submit">Upload</button>

            {loading ? (<Oval
                    height={80}
                    width={80}
                    color="#4fa94d"
                    wrapperStyle={{}}
                    wrapperClass=""
                    visible={true}
                    ariaLabel='oval-loading'
                    secondaryColor="#4fa94d"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    strokeWidthSecondary={2}

                    />) : (
                    <button
                        className='bg-blue-500 py-1 px-5 my-2'
                        type="submit">LogIn</button>
                    )}
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
// router.pathname === '/' ? 'active' : 'normal'
export default ProductUpload
```

Next js api end point:  api/upload

```
import axios from 'axios'
import cookie from 'cookie'
import {API_URL} from '../../../config/index'

export default async (req, res) =>{
  if(req.method === 'POST'){
    const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie ?? '' );
        console.log(cookies.access);
        const access = cookies.access ? true : false;
        console.log(access);

        if (access === false){
            return res.status(401).json({
                error: `User unautherized to make this request`
            });
        }
    const {
      name, 
      alt,
      img
    } = req.body

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('name', name)
    formData.append('product_images.alt', alt)
    formData.append('product_images.img1', img)
    const body = formData

    const config = {
      headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.access}`
      }}

      try{
        const apiRes = await axios.post(`${API_URL}api/products/`, body, config)
        // .then(res => console.log(res))
        // .catch(error => console.error(error))
        console.log(apiRes.constructor.name);
        console.log(apiRes.status);

        if (apiRes.status === 200){
          return res.status(200).json({'success': apiRes.data.success});
        }else{
          return res.status(400).json({"error": apiRes.data.success});
        }
      }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).json({'error': '"I cant deal with it" he said laughing through tears:) '})
      }

  }else{
    console.log(res.constructor.name);
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}
```

Django: views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ProductsSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.


class ProductListView(APIView):
    # parser_classes = [FormParser]
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, Format=None):
        use = self.request.user
        serializer = ProductsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=use)
            return Response(
                {'success': 'Product list/created successfully'},
                # status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                {'error': 'BADDDDDDDDDDDD'},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers, fields


class ProductImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImages
        fields = ('products', 'alt', 'img')
      


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_images = ProductImagesSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ( 'name', 'product_images', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_images = validated_data.pop('product_images')
        # user = validated_data['user'] , user=user
        products =  Products.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        ProductImages.objects.create(
                **product_images,
                products=products
            )
            
        return products
```

I checked the backend api with postman and it works fine.